# LibreOffice won't open a file

Tags: libreoffice

I tried to open a file which was fine last night. It’s a presentation file; Impress. I’m guessing it contains 70 or 80 slides.

This morning I get this messasge. What can I do now ?

> LibreOffice 4.3.3.2
>
> Read-Error.
>
> Format error discovered in the file in sub-document content.xml at position 2,604924(row,col).

[image]

Comment: It looks like the file is corrupt. You could try restoring from backup.

Comment: It sounds like the file is corrupt.  Can you still open an earlier revision of the document?

Comment: It was the first time I did this edit.  I do backups once a week.

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite ZIP utility to unZip a copy of the file.

Use you favorite XML editor to open the file `content.xml`.

Look at position 2,604924 and try to figure out what is wrong.  Once you’ve found the error (a misspelling, a duplicate property, that kind of thing), fix it. If the problem isn’t obvious, maybe post the XML code from this region as part of your question.

Save the fixed `content.xml`.

Rezip the package (make sure the file extension is `.odp`). There is a high likelihood Impress will now open the file without any errors.